# Let $G=S_n$ and fix $i \in A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and let $G_{i}=\{\alpha \in G | \alpha(i)= i\}$. Prove $G_{i} \leq G$ and find $|G_i|$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

I am not sure about $|G_i|$ but I was able to show $|G_i|$ as a subgroup as follow:

Define $\; \;$ **$\cdot$** $: G\times A \to  A$ as $\alpha.i= \alpha(i) \; \; \forall \alpha \in G, \; i\in A$

Then **$\cdot$**  is a group action of $G$ on $A $ since for $\alpha, \beta \in G, \; i \in A$

$\alpha.(\beta.i) = \alpha(\beta(i)) = (\alpha\circ\beta)(i) = (\alpha \beta).i$
$\; \; $and $ \; \;I.i = I(i)= I$

Now  clearly $G_i = stab_G(i) \leq G$

I am not sure about $|G_i|$

if $\alpha \in G_i$ then $\alpha $ must fix $i$. This would be possible if $\alpha$ does not contain $i$ in its cycles. Hence $\alpha \in S_{n-1}$ and therefore, $|G_i| = (n-1)!$ Will this be correct?

EDIT : Can we show $G_i \sim S_{n-1}?$

Comment: I don't see any problem with the reasoning!!

Comment: @mathnoob is there a way to show $G_i \sim S_{n-1}$

Comment: Note that $\alpha\notin S_{n-1}$ in general, since it is defined on $\{1, \dots, n\}\setminus\{i\}$. However, you have the right idea. What you need to do is construct an isomorphism.

Comment: @Shaun Can we say that $G_i  \leq S_n $  and of order $(n-1)!$ so it has to be isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$? However, I am not able to come up with the required mapping

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @mathnoob's answer should suffice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $G_i =\{\sigma \in S_n|\sigma(i)=i\}$.

Now, define $f:G_n \rightarrow G_i$ by $f(\sigma)=\phi$.

Here
 $$\phi(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \sigma(i) & x=n \\
      \ n & \sigma(x)=i \\
      \sigma(x) & \text{otherwise}. 
   \end{cases}
$$

This defines an isomorphism between $G_i$ and $G_n$ and since $G_n$ is really $S_{n-1}$, we get the isomorphism between $G_i$ and $S_{n-1}$.